# Как построить график на Ruby on Rails (не отображаются данные из одного столбца)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, morris.js

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь простроить график с помощью гема Morris, но он не видит значение одной из колонок.
Есть таблица, если брать другие данные которые находятся в БД, то график работает правильно. Но у меня в таблице в одной из колонок выводятся данные, которые в БД не хранятся, а рассчитываются в модели.
Вот построение графика графика

```
Morris.Bar({
      element: 'doc_diagram',
      data: $('#doc_diagram').data('doctor'),
      xkey: 'doctor_first_name',
      ykeys: ['current_money'],
      labels: ['Series A']
    });
```

Вот его вывод

```
%= content_tag :div, "", id: "doc_diagram", data: {doctor: 
    @doctor} %>
```

Вывод таблицы

```
<% @doctor.each do |doc| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= doc.doctor_first_name %></td>
        <td><%= doc.doctor_second_name %></td>
        <td><%= doc.current_money %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Переглянути', doc %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

В этой таблице интересует значение current_money. Знаю, что назвал неудачно но сути это пока не меняет. Это значение отображает сколько заработал доктор за прошлую неделю. Вот формула

```
def current_money
    doctor_hour_price.to_f*users.where("enter_date >= ?", 7.days.ago).count
  end
```

В этой формуле я умножаю зарплату врача за час на количество пациентов за последних 7 дней.
Вопросы такие: почему график не видит это значение если оно не сохранено в БД? Как его сохранить в БД, если миграцию я создал (не выходит отправить данные в базу данных)? Или как обойти эту проблему?

Comment: Сравните "исходный код" в браузере у рабочего варианта и нерабочего